# jquery send email with attachment

Tags: php, jquery, email

i have one form which collect user information

```
Name
Age
CV
```

and then i submit that form via jquery to send email

i have following code

```
var a= $('#a').attr('value');
var b= $('#b').attr('value');

          $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendemail.php",
            data: "a="+ a +"&b="+ b,
            success: function(html){
                         .............
```

this function works file but i am unable to find a way to verify file as MSWORD or PDF and then attach and send email.

and i am using php mail() function to send email

```
$Headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$Headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$Headers .= "From: ".$FromName." <".$FromEmail.">\n";
$Headers .= "Reply-To: ".$ReplyTo."\n";
$Headers .= "X-Sender: <".$FromEmail.">\n";
$Headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; 
$Headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; 
$Headers .= "Return-Path: <".$FromEmail.">\n";  
        if(mail($ToEmail, $Subject, $Content, $Headers) == false) {
    echo "2";
        }
        else
        { 
        echo "1" ;
        }


my basic question is:
1. how to validate file (only MSWORD and PDF)
2. send file to sendemail.php via AJAX to attach with email.
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Comment: are you just sending the file by email or storing that on your server as well?

Comment: sending file in email as attachment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) library which handles email very nicely. You could send emails with attachments to multiple recipients at a time using this library.

Comment: dear Friend thanks for reply and i know this PHPMailer, i have also used this some times. but i need to use Jquery and php for this.

Comment: PHPMailer is a PHP library. You could use this library inside your sendemail.php file according to your requirements.

Comment: yes but my basic question remain same, how to validate file and then pass by jquery to sendemail.php for attachment. thanks

Comment: You cant manage files with jquery. Anyway first you have to send it to server, then validate. You cant trust nor file size, nor anything whats coming from user. You can upload file in background using iframe and then replay with jquery.

Comment: @Ernestas Stankevičius: He can upload files using JQuery, you may consider JQuery plugins like uploadify (www.uploadify.com/). Using this you could validate user's file, after validation and uploading attach that file using PHPMailer and bang.. you are done.

Answer (score 0):

include in your function [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

and try this:

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->From="mailer@example.com";
$mail->FromName="My site's mailer";
$mail->Sender="mailer@example.com";
$mail->AddReplyTo("replies@example.com", "Replies for my site");

$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Your invoice";

$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->AddAttachment('files/invoice-user-1234.pdf', 'invoice.pdf');
$mail->Body = "Please find your invoice attached.";
if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
}
else
{
   echo "Letter is sent";
}
```

Comment: thanks but my question is still same, $mail->AddAttachment('files/invoice-user-1234.pdf', 'invoice.pdf');
this is not fixed file, this is file from user. how i send selected file from FORM to sendemail.php file for further processing?

Comment: but the form the user selects an input of file type or select a file name already exists on the system?